# How to filter a boolean value using $filter('orderBy')

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have a list of employees and there is a field called mobile, which has a value of true or false.  I want to be able to do a `$filter('orderBy')` on this "mobile" field using angularJS.  For example, I want to be able to filter the list of  employees where all the employees that have the "mobile" field set to `true` to appear at the top of the list.

I do NOT want to do this in the `ng-repeat`.  I want to do this inside my code for various reasons.  Anyway, I have the following code, but the employees that have the "mobile" field set to `true` is NOT appearing on top of the list as I would like.  Can you please tell me how I can achieve this using `$filter('orderBy')` method?

**Here are the code:**

```
col = "mobile";
$scope.employees = $filter('orderBy')($scope.employees, col);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False values are less than true values in Javascript (0 < 1); that's why employees with `mobile = false` come first after you have them sorted by that property.

So in order to accomplish what you want, you just need to change the sort order in `orderBy` by prefixing the property name with a - (dash):

```
$scope.employees = $filter('orderBy')($scope.employees, '-mobile');
```

Working plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0dNEjigFyDJ6HONmLZh6?p=preview).

You can find more information on the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) about the `orderBy` filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Sg9YY/

Because you don't want the filter in the ng-repeat, you need to provide filtered contacts:

```
$scope.filteredEmployees=angular.copy($scope.employees);
```

Then you can watch for whatever event, and then apply the filter in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch('sort',function(){
    if($scope.sort=='none'){
        $scope.filteredEmployees=angular.copy($scope.employees);
    }else{
        $scope.filteredEmployees=$filter('orderBy')($scope.employees,'myVar',$scope.sort);
    }
});
```